# Android: Floating Bar in Layout

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to add a floating bar that will stay at the top of a layout page, even when a user is scrolling through the contents of that layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add that bar at the top of your layout, and wrap the rest of the content with a `ScrollView`. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Header -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your header"/>

    <!-- rest of your layout -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Foo"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bar"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Baz"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="etc"/>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

That way, the wrapped part of your view will be scrollable while the *header* will remain in the same site.

Comment: +1 I need something similar, but instead I need that floating popup at the bottom, good starting point though!